# Date Format in C# Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to convert date format as `5/Sep/2015 11:53 AM` using Linq To Entities. Please see my code below.

```
public string DeliveryRequiredOn { get; set; }

var _orderdetails =
(
    from o in context.orders
    where o.StoreId == _storeId
        && o.CustomerId == _customerId
        && excludeStatusId.Contains(o.OrderStatusId.Value)
    select new OrderView()
    {
        OrderId = o.OrderId,
        StoreId = o.StoreId,
        DeliveryRequiredOn = o.DeliveryRequiredOn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
        BaseTotal = o.BaseTotal,
    }
).ToList();
```

How to do this using Linq.

Comment: The date '5/Sep/2015 11:53 AM' does seem to relate to the code. The code has `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`, but that's a different format. Can you please be more specific as to what you want?

Comment: I want the format as 5/Sep/2015 11:53 AM. i am trying to do the same. but i am not able to do. please help me

Comment: That's still not helpful. What does "i am trying to do the same" mean? I don't see where that particular date fits in to your code?

Comment: i don't know how to do. i am trying with my knowledge.

Comment: I think you just need MMM as your month specifier.

Comment: Vijay, I think Egnimativity's question was WHICH date would like like formatted that way. I think we can assume that you o.DeliveryRequiredOn to be formatted that way.

Comment: @NickBailey Yes, o.DeliveryRequiredOn. but i am not able compile this code getting error as No overload for method 'ToString' takes a arguments

Comment: @kidshaw i am getting error as No overload for method 'ToString' takes a arguments

Comment: So o.DeliveryRequiredOn is a string? In that case please show us an example of what it contains. Most likely will then be a combination of the answers given.

Comment: Also, why is a date being stored as a string in your database? That seems like a bigger problem.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NickBailey, good question. in database its stored as DateTime only. but i want to pass this date time value to mobile. i am passing as JSON string. mobile side the json date format is not easy to convert and display. that's why in linq itself i want to convert this format and send to mobile. then its easy to display.

Comment: So what type is o.DeliveryRequiredOn then?

Comment: @NickBailey type is public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeliveryRequiredOn { get; set; }

Comment: @VijayP.V - All of the above points, such as the error message you're getting, the data types, and what property you want help with, should have all been part of your original question. Please don't make us ask so many questions and need to read so many comments.

Comment: @VijayP.V Have you tried `AsEnumerable()` i-e `from o in context.orders.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: Thanks @X-TECH, thanks a lot. its working. I missed AsEnumerable() in linq query. one more thing, i want to correct in the date output. now Output is 28/Aug/2015 17:03 PM, i want to display 5:03 instead of 17:03

Comment: @VijayP.V use small h i-e `hh` instead of `HH`, because `hh` represents `00-12AM/PM` and `HH` shows `00-24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your format:

```
DeliveryRequiredOn = o.DeliveryRequiredOn.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

I am assuming your question means, how to set the string `DeliveryRequiredOn` to a formatted date string where the month is shown using a short description instead of a number.

Comment: when i write the line getting error as No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @VijayP.V As you said `o.DeliveryRequiredOn` is `DateTime` so it should not give error on it.

Comment: Amended to support nullable date time.

Comment: Thanks. but i tried what you have modified code. now when i compile the project i am getting entity error as 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Thanks a lot @kidshaw, its working. I missed AsEnumerable() in linq query. one more thin i want to correct in the date output. now Output is 28/Aug/2015 17:03 PM, i want to display 5:03 instead of 17:03

Comment: Glad you got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I belive

```
"dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt"
```

would be the format you require.

However, DateTime.ToString(string) is not mapped to a canonical SQL function, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738681(v=vs.100).aspx). Still, EF might still bring in the database value and compute the formatted value locally, I cannot test this now. You will have to give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: If it fits not work due to EF no having the ToString function, enumerate the IEnumerable using ToList before doing the Select.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 10,11,53,17);
         string str = dt.ToString("dd,MMM,yyyy h :mm :ss tt ");
        Console.WriteLine("Date is " +str);
```

Hope it will help for you. thanks